# SQLite- how to insert data in ios

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

i tried some sqlite program for practice when i insert the record with this code it give some error

```
-(void) insertRecordIntoTableNamed:(NSString *) tableName
                            withField1:(NSString *) field1
                           field1Value:(NSString *) field1Value
                             andField2:(NSString *) field2
                           field2Value:(NSString *) field2Value {
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"INSERT INTO ‘%@‘ (‘%@‘, ‘%@‘) VALUES (‘%@‘,’%@‘)",tableName, field1, field2, field1Value, field2Value];
        char *err;
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_close(db);
            NSAssert(0, @"Error updating table.");
        }
    }
```

the error message is

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error updating table.'
```

i try to insert data through terminal and the data is retrived properly

so Please help me for inserting data through programms

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Comment: ... So what is the error code that `sqlite3_exec` is returning? We know it's *not* `SQLITE_OK`, but there are [a couple dozen other things it could be](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html).

Answer (score 2):

may it works better when you use a char * as sql statement as an NSString object. For example:

char *sql = "INSERT INTO ‘?‘ (‘?‘, ‘?‘) VALUES (‘?‘ ....";

to replace the ? with your NSString arguments use the function below.

sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 1, [tableName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 2, [field1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
etc....

First you have to define the insert_statement.
static sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement = nil;
... and at the end you should reset the statement with sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);

Comment: He is using `[sql UTF8String]` which converts it to a C character pointer and works just fine.

Comment: @lnafziger the purpose of using `sqlite3_bind_text` is for semantic correctness, to simplify having to escape strings, and to prevent against injection attacks.

Comment: @DaveDeLong: While I get that, it wouldn't explain why this isn't working here so this doesn't really answer the question...

Answer (score 1):

LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK is unsuitable for quoting either identifiers or values in SQLite. Quote identifiers with " (\x22) and data with ' (\x27).

Also, I hope your program is simple enough that potential SQL injection doesn't matter.